# Turn off crontab log

Tags: cron

The log file is located at `/var/log/cron`. Its size grows too fast and it seems to contain a lot of unimportant data that I would never want to see. So I try to find a way to turn it off but still don't know how.

Here are some more details about the crontab:

```
crontab -l
*/5 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate 10.0.1.10
*/1 * * * * cd /tmp && netstat -an|awk '/tcp/ {print $6}'|sort|uniq -c > net.tmp && mv -f net.tmp net.cache
*/1 * * * * /script/svrcheck/openvpn.sh > /dev/null 2>&1


tail /var/log/cron
Dec 17 09:25:01 HB04 crond[54509]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/ntpdate 10.0.1.10)
Dec 17 09:25:01 HB04 crond[54500]: (root) CMD (/script/svrcheck/openvpn.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 17 09:25:01 HB04 crond[54504]: (root) CMD (cd /tmp && netstat -an|awk '/tcp/ {print $6}'|sort|uniq -c > net.tmp && mv -f net.tmp net.cache)
```

Please let me know if I could provide you more info.

Comment: You probably can't, but if you can it would be in the man page for `crond`.

Comment: Why don't you just set it to rotate more frequently and keep fewer old logs, in your `logrotate` configuration file?

Comment: Thanks, so I have to write some script to delete the log file every week?

Comment: Did you mean files like cron.1, cron.2...? I'm a newbie, will learn more about `crond` and `logrotate`.

Comment: You'll learn more if you go to the correct Stack Exchange site. SO is for programming, not system administration. Try unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can control logging using syslog.conf

comment the cron entry inside the syslog.conf  as follows .

```
 auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log

 *.*;auth,authpriv.none,cron.none  -/var/log/syslog

  #cron.*                         /var/log/cron
```

and restart the syslog.

Comment: normally /etc/rc.d/init.d/syslog restart  or /etc/init.d/syslog restart

Comment: I edited `/etc/syslog.conf` then `/etc/init.d/syslog restart`. It worked. Thank you.